# Add NLog provider to ILoggerFactory

Tags: dependency-injection, nlog, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add NLog as a provider to my logger factory in my startup.cs file, but I can't seem to add it. All the examples I have seen do this:

```cs
loggerFactory.AddNLog(new global::NLog.LogFactory());
```

I am using:

```json
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta2"
```

From what I can tell in the GitHub examples, etc., this no longer exists:

```json
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog": "1.0.0-*"
```

So I'd like to know what it has been replaced with (`"NLog": "3.2.0.0"` ?), and what is the correct way to add an NLog provider in my startup file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logging sample in the ASP.NET GitHub repo that shows how to use NLog: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/samples/SampleApp

The sample uses a sample NLog logging adapter from here: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog

Here's the `project.json` file from the app: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/project.json

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant part of the `project.json` file from the sample NLog adapter with the actual NLog dependency:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
        "NLog": "3.1.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": { },
        "aspnet50": { }
    }
}
```

Please note that currently NLog works on `aspnet50` (.NET 4.x) only and not on `aspnetcore50` (Core CLR).

Also note that because the NLog adapter is a *sample*, the ASP.NET team doesn't officially publish the adapter, so you'll need to grab the source code yourself and use it.

Comment: I think I responded a little too quick. Those were the samples I was looking at before I posted the q, however my issue is that  "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog": "1.0.0-*" does not exist. In your example, the project.json file is referencing that, and that cannot be resolved in VS.

Comment: @yhax as I mentioned, the NLog adapter is just a sample and is not shipped. You'll have to grab the code from GitHub and use it yourself (for now).

Comment: now all the links are dead